# Connecting to oracle from C# without a password

Tags: c#, oracle

I have successfully finished a small C# program that inserts into an oracle database using  odp.net just to find out I am not allowed to type in (or even know) the password to connect to the database. I am therefore forced to use an inbetween step that will not be configured by me. Is there an existing interphase or a method I am not finding to connect in such a way?

Comment: You created a C# program which uses Java JDBC? - Very unlikely.

Comment: You're right, I don't know why that reference is there, sorry.

Comment: Can you use LDAP/SSO?  There is no thing as an "anonymous" connection in oracle.  You have to authenticate somehow.  This sounds more like an administration issue, where DBAs are not configuring proper roles and access rights.